# android save transparent Image

Tags: android, save, transparent

I am trying to save an image with transparent channel on android.
we have try to use android Bitmap.compress

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
superImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);//quality 0 also have tried
out.flush();
out.close();
```

also,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
superImage.setHasAlpha(true);
superImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,0,stream);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
os.write(stream.toByteArray());
os.close();
```

But we fail to save the image:

for the src image is like this(we do it on one PC):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKAro.png)

with green points around the boundary.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBb1d.png)

I have found the why it failed ,the green points around the boundary have the opacity between 20~245,do you have any suggestion？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using LodePng,and the libpng is also useful.This a bug for Bitmap.compress.